# i can't change my carousel to full screen

Tags: html, css

this is the code i am not able to make the carousel full screen
i have used width 100% still it doesnt change occupy the whole screen
i used bootstrap in this project
would be helpful if someone can help me. thank you

```
<html>
        <head>
                <link href="homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <style>
                    .container{
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;
                    }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="slide">
                <div class="container p-4">
                    <div class="w-100 h-50">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselExample" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="roughslide1.jpg" alt="FIRST SLIDE" class="d-block w-100 h-100">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="roughslide2.jpg" alt="SECOND SLIDE" class="d-block w-100 h-100">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item ">
                                    <img src="roughslide3.jpg" alt="THIRD SLIDE" class="d-block w-100 h-100">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#carouselExample" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">PREVIOUS</span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#carouselExample" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">NEXT</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your carousel is inside a div with the class `container`. In Bootstrap containers on default have a `max-width` that depends on the `breakpoint`.

```
Breakpoint  container-width
xs         |           100%
sm         |           540px
md         |           720px
lg         |           960px
xl         |           1140px
```

- You can however change it to `container-fluid` to avoid that native
  scaling of `containers`.
- You added a `p-4` class to your `container`    as well, I guess
  that's intentional, but will add a padding to each    side.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `carousel` class sets `max-width` and class `p-4` sets `padding` so that there always remains space on the sides. If you get rid of these classes your carousel will take the full width (assuming that's all the code you have).

Answer (score 0):

Change **container** class to **container-fluid** and it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To fix your snippet I had to make two changes only:

first removing the uncalled for  `<div class="container p-4"></div>`and
`<div class="w-100 h-50"></div>`
and then I made sure to change the `h-100` class you give to `img` tag  to be `vh-100` that will make sure the image is filling the page and it will be responsive without any problem. because it will always take `100%` of the height of the viewport.

Here is your code with the fix:

```
<header>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselExample" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="assets/images/image.jpg" alt="FIRST SLIDE" class="d-block w-100 vh-100">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/image.jpg" alt="SECOND SLIDE" class="d-block w-100 vh-100">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item ">
                    <img src="assets/images/image.jpg" alt="THIRD SLIDE" class="d-block w-100 vh-100">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#carouselExample" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">PREVIOUS</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#carouselExample" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">NEXT</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Also, Check this working snippet I hope this can be any help.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080 " class="d-block w-100 vh-100" alt="pic-1">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-2">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-3">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-4">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-5">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```